# Unable to find invoice while receiving payments in Quickbooks online

Tags: quickbooks-online

Unable to find invoice while receiving payments in Quickbooks online.

I am expecting that when I search invoice in receive payments it appears and I easily get my receive payment done.

I have to apply payments on more that 1000 invoices in single transaction.